# Form doesn't show up in excel on ribbon button press after publishing

Tags: c#, excel, winforms, office365

The form shows up fine when pressing the button in debug and after publish in the user the project is in, but on a different user the form doesn't show up.

```
public partial class Ribbon1
{
    private void newIron_Click(object sender, RibbonControlEventArgs e)
    {
        IronForm form = new IronForm();
        form.Visible();
    }
}

public partial class IronForm : Form
{
    public IronForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.FixedSingle; // makes form non resizeable
    }

    // path - photo path
    public void ChangeUC(string uc, string path = "")
    {
        if (uc == "ms")
        {
            string image = path;
            this.measurements1.pictureBox1.Load(Path.Combine(Globals.ThisAddIn.path + @"\lengths", path + ".png"));
            this.measurements1.sketchPath = Path.Combine(Globals.ThisAddIn.path, path + ".png");
            string[] data = File.ReadAllLines(Globals.ThisAddIn.path + @"\sides.cfg");
            foreach (string line in data)
            {
                if (line.Split('-')[0] == image)
                {
                    this.measurements1.sides = int.Parse(line.Split('-')[1]);
                    break;
                }
            }
            // shows textbox for the amount of sides 
            if (this.measurements1.sides > 0)
            {
                for (int i = 1; i <= this.measurements1.sides; i++)
                {
                    this.measurements1.entries[i].Visible = true;
                    this.measurements1.labelsEntries[i].Visible = true;
                }
                this.measurements1.Visible = true;
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("sides error");
                this.sketches1.Visible = true;
            }
        }
        
        else if (uc == "sk")
        {
            this.sketches1.Visible = true;
        }
        
    }
}
```

I've tried changing `form.Visible` to `form.Show` and `form.ShowDialog` but that didn't do anything.

I tried to publish a simple form and it worked fine. Showing a `MessageBox` works fine.

Anybody know what I need to do?

Comment: You might want to add some logging in your code so you can see how far it gets when it's not running under debug mode.

Comment: Thanks, I managed to find the problem. I had to change the path from my username to connected user.